# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute does not contain "IsAuthorized" Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributes

I am currently trying to write my own AuthorizeAttribute, since I can not and do not want to use the built-in.
On the internet, I only find solutions everywhere that do not work for me. Everywhere an "IsAuthorized" method is overwritten, which does not seem to exist. By the way: There is no class HttpActionContext for me.

I have already tried to solve the problem with other namespaces, but without success. The only namespace that includes the needed "AuthorizeAttribute" class is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System;

namespace Project.PermissionManagement {
    public class PermissionControl : AuthorizeAttribute {
        private readonly Permission[] permissions;
        public Permission[] Permissions { get { return permissions; } }

        public PermissionControl(params Permission[] permissions) {
            this.permissions = permissions;
        }

        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
            foreach (Permission requiredPermission in permissions) {
                if (!Globals.CurrentUser.Permissions.Contains(requiredPermission))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Originally, the idea was to protect any method with an attribute. Any user without the correct rights should be redirected to an error page.
This should look somethink like this:

```
[PermissionControl(Permission.RequiredPermission)]
void ActionForSpecialUsers() {
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: `Globals.CurrentUser` already smells terribly bad. You are looking for the wrong solution to the problem, and you are just getting worse and worse. With your code, it looks like the built-in Authorization system would be just fine with claims/roles

Comment: I have to echo what @CamiloTerevinto wrote. I also suspect the samples you found are for a different version of ASP.Net. Did you take a look at the [policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2)? It offers many ways to customize it.